# sql oracle прогноз оптимизация

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация

Помогите, пожалуйста, оптимизировать код.
Eсть табл

```
MONTH      REGION SEGMENT       Revo  
01.01.2023 Восток FMC           496,85  
01.02.2023 Восток FMC           537,71  
01.03.2023 Восток FMC           564,77  
01.04.2023 Восток FMC           436,73  
01.05.2023 Восток FMC           398,35  
01.06.2023 Восток FMC           262,72  
01.07.2023 Восток FMC           182,28  
01.08.2023 Восток FMC           305,13  
01.09.2023 Восток FMC           341,97  
01.10.2023 Восток FMC   
01.11.2023 Восток FMC   
01.12.2023 Восток FMC
```

У нас есть столбец month с января по сентябрь есть значения по Rev0,
Мне нужно сделать прогноз  для октября как среднее значение за 3 предыдущих месяца.
Для ноября значение за август , сентябрь  и прогнозное значение за октября. Для декабря прогнозное значение за ноябрь и октябрь и факт сентября. Как можно делать расчет с прогнозными значениями постоянно не смещая столбцы. (это урезанная часть таблицы, расчетов намного больше)

```
--1 таблица это смещение показателей в разрезе:
месяца, сегмента и региона:
CREATE TABLE table1 as
with
stage22 as (select CALL_MONTH, REV0, GLOBAL_REGION, "SEGMENT_"
from table0),  
              
stage2 as (select CALL_MONTH, sum(REV0) as REV0_h,   GLOBAL_REGION,  "SEGMENT_"
from stage22
group by CALL_MONTH, GLOBAL_REGION, "SEGMENT_"),
   m1 as (select add_months(CALL_MONTH,1) as month_m1, REV0_h as REV0_hm1, "SEGMENT_", GLOBAL_REGION from stage2),
       m2 as (select add_months(CALL_MONTH,2) as month_m2, REV0_h as REV0_hm2, "SEGMENT_", GLOBAL_REGION from stage2),
         m3 as (select add_months(CALL_MONTH,3) as month_m3, REV0_h as REV0_hm3, "SEGMENT_", GLOBAL_REGION from stage2)

select S.*,REV0_hm1, REV0_hm2, REV0_hm3 from  table0 S

left join m1 on S.CALL_MONTH = m1.month_m1 and S.segment_=m1."SEGMENT_" and S.GLOBAL_REGION=m1.GLOBAL_REGION
left join m2 on S.CALL_MONTH = m2.month_m2 and S.segment_=m2."SEGMENT_" and S.GLOBAL_REGION=m2.GLOBAL_REGION
left join m3 on S.CALL_MONTH = m3.month_m3 and S.segment_=m3."SEGMENT_" and S.GLOBAL_REGION=m3.GLOBAL_REGION;
```

```
---2 таблица это расчет на основании смещенных данных (здесь расчет до октября включительно):

create table sus_Rev11_inb_prognoz as 
select distinct CALL_MONTH, GLOBAL_REGION, SEGMENT_,
          ROUND((avg(REV0_hm1+REV0_hm2+REV0_hm3))/3,2)  as REv0
     from table1
group by CALL_MONTH, GLOBAL_REGION, SEGMENT_
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написал так:
`calc_month` - это месяц, среднее по которому сейчас рассчитывается

```
with t as (
    select to_date('01.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region, 496.85 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region, 537.71 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region, 564.77 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.04.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region, 436.73 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.05.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region, 398.35 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.06.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region, 262.72 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.07.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region, 182.28 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region, 305.13 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region, 341.97 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region,   null as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.11.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region,   null as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.12.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Восток' as region,   null as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,      1 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.02.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,      1 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,      1 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.04.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,      1 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.05.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,      2 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.06.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,      2 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.07.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,      2 as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,   null as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.09.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,   null as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,   null as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.11.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,   null as rev0 from dual union all
    select to_date('01.12.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') as month, 'Запад'  as region,   null as rev0 from dual
),
prognoz (month, region, rev0, calc_month) as (
    select
        month,
        region,
        rev0,
        to_date('01.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
    from t
    union all
    select
        month,
        region,
        nvl(rev0,
            case month when calc_month then
                avg(rev0) over (partition by region order by month rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding)
            end
        ),
        add_months(calc_month, 1)
    from
        prognoz p
    where
        calc_month < to_date('01.01.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
)
select month, region, rev0 from prognoz
where calc_month = to_date('01.01.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
order by region, month
```

Comment: спасибо за предложенный ответ, при использовании данного запроса возникает ошибка ORA-32044 "Обнаружен цикл при выполнении рекурсивного запроса"

Comment: при выполнении этого запроса циклы невозможны, т.к. разные поколения строк отличаются значением столбца `calc_month`.  наверное, циклы возникают в другом запросе, который вы нам не показали.